# Sitemesh spring:message not recognized in template

Tags: java, spring, jsp, decorator, sitemesh

We are using the spring:message tag in a project with Sitemesh 2.
When using the spring:message in the decorator than the -tag isn't recognized. We can use the -tag in our jsp pages but in the decorator jsp file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<excludes/>

<page-parsers>
    <parser content-type="text/html" encoding="UTF-8" class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.FastPageParser" />
</page-parsers>

<decorator-mappers>
    <mapper class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.mapper.ConfigDecoratorMapper">
        <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}" />
    </mapper>
</decorator-mappers>
```

If we use the deprecated parser FastPageParser than there is no problem, but when using the new HTMLPageParser than is doesn't work.

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<spring:message code="msg.x.x.x"  />
```

Works fine for me on decorators using FastPageParser.

A couple of things to check..

- Are you including the springframework and sitemesh taglibs on your decorators?
- I'm not sure if it will make a difference to the filter chain, but I'm using a custom configdecorator mapper that chooses the decorator based on a layout set in the request scope.

So in sitemesh.xml:

```
<decorator-mappers>
    <mapper class="org.x.x.CustomConfigDecoratorMapper">
        <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}" />
    </mapper>
</decorator-mappers>
```

CustomConfigDecoratorMapper look's like this:

```
public class CustomConfigDecoratorMapper extends AbstractDecoratorMapper {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomConfigDecoratorMapper.class);
    private ConfigLoader configLoader = null;

    public void init(Config config, Properties properties, DecoratorMapper parent) throws InstantiationException
    {
        super.init(config, properties, parent);
        try
        {
            String fileName = properties.getProperty("config", "/WEB-INF/decorators.xml");
            configLoader = new ConfigLoader(fileName, config);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            throw new InstantiationException(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Decorator getDecorator(HttpServletRequest request, Page page)
    {
            String layoutName = "default";

            String configLayoutName = ( String)request.getParameter("layoutName" );
            if ( configLayoutName == null )
            {
                    configLayoutName = (String)request.getAttribute("layoutName");
                    if ( configLayoutName == null )
                    {
                            configLayoutName = "default";
                    }
            }
            if ( configLayoutName != null )
            {
                    layoutName = configLayoutName;
            }

            Decorator result = getNamedDecorator(request, layoutName);
            return result == null ? super.getDecorator(request, page) : result;
    }

    public Decorator getNamedDecorator(HttpServletRequest request, String name)
    {
            Decorator result = null;
            try
            {
                    result = configLoader.getDecoratorByName(name);
            }
            catch (ServletException e)
            {
                    logger.error("getNamedDecorator(HttpServletRequest, String)", e);
            }
            if (result == null || (result.getRole() != null && !request.isUserInRole(result.getRole())))
            {
                    return super.getNamedDecorator(request, name);
            }
            else
            {
                    return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Other than that.. have you considered using fmt:message instead?